# localStorage state value of undefined after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, use-effect

I'm trying to pass my state value to another page and store it to my localStorage. The state has been stored and it works the first time I run my application. However, my localStorage value keep saying undefined every time I refresh the page. For what I understand, the localStorage value will always be there until I delete the value in localStorage. I tried to modify my if/else statement inside my Hook useEffect function. Here's my code:

I'm passing state from this page using:

```
<Link to={{
                       pathname: "/product/description",
                       infoObj: {
                           text: "This is information passed on",
                           state: {
                               ...props
                           },
                       }
                   }}>
                        Product Description
                   </Link>
```

And I'm accessing the state from another page and set it to localStorageusing:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const stateInfo = JSON.stringify(props.location.infoObj);
    localStorage.setItem("info", stateInfo);
}, [])
```

This is how I access my item in my localStorage:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"));
    if(!localStorage.getItem("info") || getInfo.length === 0){
        try{
            localStorage.setItem("info", JSON.stringify(props.location.infoObj));
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
},[])
```

Really appreciate helps from y'all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `localStorage` will persist during the page refreshes or closing the page/browser, but the additional data that you pass during the page transition via `location.infoObj` won't. So what ends up happening is that your code overwrites the localStorage with the `props.location.infoObj` which will be undefined after a refresh.

To fix it you can add additional condition in your first `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const stateInfo = JSON.stringify(props.location.infoObj);
  if(stateInfo) {
    localStorage.setItem("info", stateInfo);
  }
}, [])
```